# Multiple levels of hub-sites do not affect hub site navigation & search

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, administration, hub-site

We have 3 site:

1. Root site @ /
2. Departments site @ /sites/Departments
3. HR site @ /sites/HR

And we defined the following hub site settings:

1. Register Root & Departments sites as hub sites.
2. Define Root as the hub site for Departments
3. Define Departments as the hub site for HR

but we got weird results:

1. Inside the HR site >> we only got the hub navigation for the Departments site and not for both Root and Department (since Root is the hub for Department), as follow:

[image]

So how we can fix this issue and show the 2 Hub sites navigations inside the HR site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of associating a hub site with another hub site is to expand the search results across multiple hubs, when a user searches from an associated site. It is not to allow navigation to be inherited down multiple levels of hubs. You can read more about how hub to hub associations work here:

[Associate a SharePoint hub site to another hub to connect search experiences](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/hub-to-hub-association)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

This is by design in SharePoint. A SharePoint site inherits only one hub navigation from it's direct parent hub site.

**Documentations**:

1. [Planning your SharePoint hub sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites)
2. [Associate a SharePoint hub site to another hub to connect search experiences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hub-to-hub-association)